# Problems with including page references in a citation

Tags: natbib, tufte

I'm trying to cite a page reference for reference item ABC:

```
\cite[p2]{ABC}
```

However, LaTeX seems to interpret this as me trying to

```
\cite[
```

and returns, quite sensibly, the error that there is no reference with the name [. I've been using natbib and cite for quite some time and have never seen this error occur. For reference, I am using the Tufte book environment, but I doubt that has much to do with it.

Has anybody else encountered this error, and found solutions?

**UPD:** @moewe asked me to prepare a short MWE. Here:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\title{title}
\author{someone}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title}

This is some text.\cite[2]{ABC}

\bibliography{mybiblio}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

And mybibliography.bib is:

```
@book{ABC,
     Title = {Whatever.}}
```

If I try to do [p2]ABC, I get a 2 in the text stream and only the title in the reference. If I do it in the \marginnote{} environment, I get the aforementioned '[' error.

Comment: What package do you use in that particular document (you mentioned `natbib`)? Would you mind preparing a short MWE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tufte classes redefine the `cite` command so that citations appear in the margin and, although it takes an optional argument in addition to the mandatory bibkey, this argument does not serve the same purpose as it would in a regular `\cite` command. I *think* what it does is moves the sidenote down by the given distance. So TeX complains not because it does not expect an extra argument but because `p2` or `2` is not a recognised unit of measure. You could type `John\cite{john2012}, p2`, .... or use `\newcommand` to automate this.

Comment: Really? No optional argument to `\cite`? And the portability? It will be very difficulty to take a text and transform it using that class. Err...

Comment: @Sigur Indeed. On the other hand, any document you write with this class is going to be difficult or impossible to transform into one using another class in any case. I'd never heard of it before I started using this site. Now I just wish I'd never heard of it. On the other hand, I'm extremely ignorant where TeX is concerned so perhaps it is not quite as evil as it appears to me ;).

Comment: Another option (if you're willing to give up sidenote citations), is to use the `nobib` document class option and load the `natbib` package (or your favorite bibliography package) yourself. Then Tufte-LaTeX won't redefine `\cite`.